How is it that a matrix of polynomials can be represented as a circulant matrix for purposes like lattice reduction?
When using lattice reduction on polynomial matrices, I have seen examples where a matrix can be represented as a circulant matrix before lattice reduction. Is there an explanation on why this works?

Matrix of polynomials


Resultant matrix


This is because polynomial multiplication is being implemented modulo $x^4+1$. For example, suppose that we wished to multiply the polynomial $s(x)=s_3x^3+s_2x^2+s_1x+s_0$ by the polynomial in the top left hand corner of $A$ (i.e. $20x^3+128x^3+196x^2+87$). Multiplying out without reduction, but gathering together coefficients we get
$$20s_3x^6+(128s_3+20s_2)x^5+(196s_3+128s_2+20s_1)x^4+$$
$$+(87s_3+196s_2+128s_1+20s_0)x^3+(87s_2+196s_1+128s_0)x^2+(87s_1+196s_0)x+87s_0.$$
Now working modulo $x^4+1$ we have $x^6=x^2(x^4)\equiv -x^2\pmod{x^4+1}$, $x^5=x(x^4)\equiv -1\pmod{x^4+1}$, and $x^4\equiv-1\pmod{x^4+1}$. Substituting these into the above expression and regrouping we have
$$(87s_3+196s_2+128s_1+20s_0)x^3+(-20s_3+87s_2+196s_1+128s_0)x^2+$$
$$+(-128s_3020s_2+87s_1+196s_0)x+(-196s_3-128s_2-20s_1+87s_0).$$
We could also write this in matrix notation, with the coefficients of our product polynomial being given by the entries in the calculation of the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}87 & 196 & 128 & 20\\
-20 & 87 & 196 & 128\\
-128 & -20 & 87 & 196\\
-196 & -128 & -20 & 87\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}s_3\\s_2\\s_1\\s_0\end{pmatrix}$$
which is the negacirculant submatrix in the top left of your expanded matrix.
Similar steps lead to the other submatrices in the expanded form (though I think that you might want to swap the top right and bottom left submatrices).

Oh that makes sense. Is there a specific name for this rule?

To give a slightly higher-level perspective that I find useful, we associate with any polynomial $p(x)\in R_q := \mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(f(x))$ the matrix $M_{p(x)}$ associated with the linear transformation
$$v(x) \mapsto p(x)v(x)\bmod f(x),$$
defined on the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x))\cong \mathbb{Z}_q^{\deg p(x)}$. We can compute this matrix $M_{p(x)}$ in the standard way --- it's $i$th column is the image of the $i$th basis vector of $R_q$ under $M_{p(x)}$. This $i$th basis vector is (in the coefficient embedding, under a certain natural ordering) $x^i$, so

The first (properly "zeroth") column of $M_{p(x)}$ is $p(x)\cdot 1\bmod f(x)$, or just $p(x)$,
the second is $p(x)\cdot x\bmod f(x)$, and
the $i$th is $p(x)\cdot x^{i-1}\bmod f(x)$.

This is essentially what Daniel wrote, though there is one mild difference arising from him writing the coefficient vector as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
s_3\\
s_2\\
s_1\\
s_0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which orders things so $1$ is the $n-1$st basis vector, $x$ is the $n-2$nd basis vector, etc. This is a matter of personal preference of course.
As for a name for this, I believe it is just the companion matrix of $f(x)$ in a different basis, though don't 100% recall offhand.
